# Django login form on main page

Tags: python, django, forms, authentication, sections

How can i fix my login section, o cannot see input fields on my home page site. I want to have main home site with posts and small window for login on the right site:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsUV6.png)

```
def home(request):
    
    loginform= auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='site/home.html')
    
    
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all(),
        'form': loginform
    }

    return render(request, 'site/home.html', context)
```

home.html

```
{% extends "site/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
...
{% endblock content %}

{% block userpanel %}

  <div class="content-section">            
      {% if user.is_authenticated  %}
      ...
      {% else %}
      {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
          <div class="content-section">
              <form method="POST">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <fieldset class="form-group">
                      <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Zaloguj</legend>
                      {{ form|crispy }}                                
                  </fieldset>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Zaloguj</button>
                  </div>
              </form>
              <div class="border-top pt-3">
                  <small class="text-muted">
                      Potrzebujesz konta? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'register' %}">Zarejestruj</a>
                  </small>
              </div>
          </div>
      {% endif %}

{% endblock userpanel %}
```

I want to have interactive home page with content and login section